# Running an application created in windows using QT on a embedded linux platform

Tags: linux, qt, deployment, embedded, porting

I have created an application in QT 5.1.1 in windows XP OS. I want it to run on embedded Linux. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What did you try? At least you need to install QT libraries and some graphical system (DirectFB?) on Linux machine and recompile your app.

Comment: I am not working on embedded Linux. Would it be allright if I just hand over my code to those guys?

Comment: It depends on your relationships. If you not working with Linux, it's probably possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check yourself before sending it to them...

- install VirtualBox
- install a similar version of linux
- install the Qt libraries
- rebuild your application and make sure it behaves the way you want.

If you only use Qt libraries and includes, you probably won't have to change much, if anything.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I 'll try that. I will have to take care of platform dependencies in the .pro file right?

Comment: Here are some more links: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions  http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_for_Embedded_Linux http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:HowTo::Qt_Embedded